# Nginx not proxying api requests from react frontend app to flask backend

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, server

I and a colleague have built a react+flask app. We have set up all the basic server configurations and it's all working fine except for internal api calls from within the react app.

On **nginx**, I am proxying two requests, one to the **react app** and one to **flask app**. The files in the react app make requests to the flask app (api)

Somehow, nginx blocks this request. Please see my nginx of the second server configuration below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name artisan-02.myartisan.works;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         add_header X-Served-By artisan-02;
    }

    location /api/ {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         add_header X-Served-By artisan-02;
    }
}
```

Visiting the api address shows that it's indeed accessible from external sources

```
❯ curl -sL https://myartisan.works/api/v1/contractors/5
{"address":"4333 Nolan View\nMckeemouth, MN 12184","bookings":[{"booking_date":"2023-09-11T15:18:52","contract_id":null,"contractor_id":5,"id":1,"service_id":5,"status":"pending","user_id":6,"user_reviews":...}
```

This confirms that the problem only occurs when the api address is called from within the react app.

error log from nginx

```
2023/11/16 11:33:11 [error] 13480#13480: *3005 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 174.138.92.85, server: artisan-01.myartisan.works, request: "GET /static/js/bundle.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js", host: "myartisan.works"
2023/11/16 11:35:58 [error] 13480#13480: *3007 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 174.138.92.85, server: artisan-01.myartisan.works, request: "GET /api/v1/contractors HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v1/contractors", host: "myartisan.works"
```

I changed the calls from within the react app from http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v1/resource to http://127.0.0.1:80/api/v1/resource since nginx listens on port 80 for incoming http requests which I expect would then proxy to the flask instance.

Any help will be much appreciated